# Jquery on events reacting differently?

Tags: jquery, click, live

Using fullpage.js and createIT jQuery Paypal HTML Shop.
I have several elements on my website. When using below method:

```
r.on("click touchend", function(r) {
```

Everything works as expected and 1 elemnt is added to the shopping cart.

Now I need to remove and add elements dynamically and was trying to use:

```
$(document).on('click touchend', r, function (r){
```

But this adds all elements to the shopping cart?

Any idea how to handle this and why there is a difference between those two? Or how to make

```
r.on("click touchend", function(r) {
```

permanent if elements are added to the document?

Thanks

Comment: You can post it as an answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on('click touchend', ".ct-product-button", function (r){   
r.stopImmediatePropagation(),
r.preventDefault(),
```

This is what is working for me.